# to predict values in lme4

Tags: r, prediction, lme4

I used `library(lme4)` to build my model. The model is

```
modTTO <- lmer(as.numeric(`TTO value`) ~ mo2+mo3+sc2+sc3+ua2+ua3+pd2+pd3+ad2+ad3 + (1 | internal_id), TTO, REML=FALSE)
```

Now I want to `predict` values for 81 states in a new data frame. I tried
`predicted$values<-predict(modTTO, type="response")`

I got an error

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, values, value = c(-0.252543831995977,  : 
>     replacement has 3000 rows, data has 81

How do I predict values for these particular 81 states.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please read the help documentation on `predict` before posting. This is clearly described there.

`predicted$values <- predict(modTTO, newdata= predicted, type= 'repsonse')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I did, and it gave me the error

Comment: @SvetlanaRatushnyak please provide a reproducible question if you want additional help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example